# Ui state class expecting wrong parameter

Tags: android, mvvm

I am working on an Android app that uses the MVVM design pattern and use cases.

I am getting data from an API and that data is sent from the domain layer to the presentation layer or more specifically the ViewModel through use cases.
The issue is that in my viewmodel I am trying to create a `MutableStateFlow` like this:

```
 private val _weatherFlow = MutableStateFlow<UiState<WeatherModel>>(UiState.Loading)
```

but for some reason I am getting a compiler error saying:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is UiState.Loading but UiState<WeatherModel> was expected
```

Here is the setup:

This ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class WeatherViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val weatherUseCase: GetWeatherUseCase,
    private val weatherConverter: WeatherConverter
) : ViewModel() {


    //TODO fix this

    private val _weatherFlow = MutableStateFlow<UiState<WeatherModel>>(UiState.Loading)

    val weatherFlow: StateFlow<UiState<WeatherModel>> = _weatherFlow

    fun loadWeather(cityName : String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            weatherUseCase.execute(GetWeatherUseCase.Request(cityName))
                .map {
                    weatherConverter.convert(it)
                }
                .collect {
                    _weatherFlow.value = it
                }
        }
    }

}
```

is getting data through this use case:

```
class GetWeatherUseCase @Inject constructor(
    configuration: Configuration,
    private val weatherRepository: WeatherRepository
) : UseCase<GetWeatherUseCase.Request , GetWeatherUseCase.Response>(configuration){

    override fun process(request: Request): Flow<Response> =
        weatherRepository.getWeather(request.weatherDataCityName)
            .map {
                Response(it)
            }

    data class Request(val weatherDataCityName: String) : UseCase.Request
    data class Response(val weather: Weather) : UseCase.Response
}
```

in the form of an object of this data class:

```
data class Weather (
    val cityName : String,
    val latitude: Double?,
    val longitude: Double?,
    val currentWeather: CurrentWeather?,
    val hourlyWeather: List<HourlyWeather>?
)


data class CurrentWeather(
    val timestamp: Long,
    val temperature: Double,
    val feelsLike: Double,
    val humidity: Int,
    val uvi: Double,
    val cloudCover: Int,
    val visibility: Int,
    val windSpeed: Double,
    val weatherConditions: List<WeatherCondition>
)

data class HourlyWeather(
    val timestamp: Long,
    val temperature: Double,
    val feelsLike: Double,
    val humidity: Int,
    val uvi: Double,
    val cloudCover: Int,
    val windSpeed: Double,
    val weatherConditions: List<WeatherCondition>,
    val chanceOfRain: Double
)

data class WeatherCondition(
    val conditionId: Int,
    val mainDescription: String,
    val detailedDescription: String,
    val icon: String
)
```

The presentation layer is using this class to handle the different states:

```
sealed class UiState<T : Any> {

    data object Loading : UiState<Nothing>()

    data class Error<T : Any>(val errorMessage: String) : UiState<T>()

    data class Success<T : Any>(val data: T) : UiState<T>()

}
```

I am not sure if it is relevant but I will include it anyway, the viewmodel uses this converter class to convert the Weather DTO to the presentation layer WeatherModel data class:

```
class WeatherConverter @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val context: Context) :
    CommonResultConverter<GetWeatherUseCase.Response, WeatherModel>() {
    override fun convertSuccess(data: GetWeatherUseCase.Response): WeatherModel {
        val cityName = context.getString(R.string.center_location_text, data.weather.cityName)

        val currentWeather = data.weather.currentWeather?.let { it ->
            WeatherModel.CurrentWeatherModel(
                it.timestamp,
                it.temperature,
                it.feelsLike,
                it.humidity,
                it.uvi,
                it.visibility,
                it.windSpeed,
                it.weatherConditions.map { WeatherModel.WeatherConditionModel(it.mainDescription) }
            )
        } ?: WeatherModel.CurrentWeatherModel(0L, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0.0, 0, 0.0, emptyList())

        val hourlyWeather = data.weather.hourlyWeather?.take(3)?.map {
            WeatherModel.HourlyWeatherModel(
                it.timestamp,
                it.temperature,
                WeatherModel.WeatherConditionModel(it.weatherConditions[0].mainDescription)
            )
        } ?: emptyList()

        return WeatherModel(
            cityName,
            currentWeather,
            hourlyWeather
        )
    }
}

abstract class CommonResultConverter<T : Any, R : Any> {

    fun convert(result: Result<T>): UiState<R> {
        return when (result) {
            is Result.Error -> {
                UiState.Error(result.exception.localizedMessage.orEmpty())
            }
            is Result.Success -> {
                UiState.Success(convertSuccess(result.data))
            }
        }
    }

    abstract fun convertSuccess(data: T): R
}


data class WeatherModel(
    val cityName: String,
    val currentWeather: CurrentWeatherModel,
    val hourlyWeather: List<HourlyWeatherModel>
) {
    data class CurrentWeatherModel(
        val timestamp: Long,
        val temperature: Double,
        val feelsLike: Double,
        val humidity: Int,
        val uvi: Double,
        val visibility: Int,
        val windSpeed: Double,
        val weatherConditions: List<WeatherConditionModel>
    )

    data class HourlyWeatherModel(
        val timestamp: Long,
        val temperature: Double,
        val weatherCondition: WeatherConditionModel
    )

    data class WeatherConditionModel(
        val mainDescription: String
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update sealed class from `sealed class UiState<T : Any>` to `sealed class UiState<out T>` by adding the out keyword in the class declaration.

```
sealed class UiState<out T> {
   data object Loading : UiState<Nothing>()

   data class Error<T>(val errorMessage: String) : UiState<T>()

   data class Success<T>(val data: T) : UiState<T>()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey your sealed class should pass the correct type of the model then it should work

```
sealed class UiState<T> {
    object Loading : UiState<WeatherModel>()
    data class Error<T : Any>(val errorMessage: String) : UiState<T>()
    data class Success<T : Any>(val data: T) : UiState<T>()
}
```

or if you want to keep it generic:

```
class Loading<T : Any> : UiState<T>()
```